# Multiple geodist criteria for one query?

Tags: sphinx

Is there any way to:

a. provide two sets of geodist criteria
    for a single query; or
 b. chain queries together to do one
    geodist query, then another based on
    the results of the first one?

Alternatively, does anyone have any other suggestions on how to calculate the intersection of two geodis-based searches, as highlighted by the red area in the following image:

http://cl.ly/0v3m1L1P3U200l1P2C3d

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set multiple GEODIST expression in same query. It finally looks like

```
mysql> SELECT *, GEODIST ( x1, y1, lat_attr, lon_attr ) as c1, GEODIST ( x2, y2, lat_attr, lon_attr ) as c2 FROM YOUR_INDEX where c1<blue_dist and c2<yellow_dist
```

or

```
mysql> SELECT *, GEODIST ( x1, y1, lat_attr, lon_attr ) as c1, GEODIST ( x2, y2, lat_attr, lon_attr ) as c2, c1<blue_dist and c2<yellow_dist as yellow_cond FROM YOUR_INDEX where yellow_cond=1
```

where x1, y1, x2, y2, blue_dist, red_dist are USER defined constants